# Problem Installing Lispy Package Manager

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I am installing Hunchentoot on a new machine.  This time I thought I would try out Lispy, because it appears to be simplest way of managing the dependencies for Hunchentoot in a standard and hopefully automatic way.  However, when I install it, it trips on not being able to verify a key.  I have seen ASDF-INSTALL try to use a key before, and I have normally found some way to skip verifying the key.  I don't really need that kind of security, I trust the people distributing these packages, OK?  Anyway, in this case there is no restart to skip the key, so rather than dig into the code and hack my way out of it, I was wondering if there is a more correct way to deal with this.  I assume Lispy isn't supposed to be broken and I am using the most standard and supported environment imaginable for Common Lisp: Ubuntu + sbcl.  I figure I could make this work, but then again I could just install all the dependencies for Hunchentoot manually using ASDF-INSTALL just as easily, so I figure I'll give Lispy a shot and do it in a more controlled and correct way.  Here's the actual log of what I did, cutting out most of the in-between messages:

```
* (load "asdf-config.lisp")

T
* (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :lispy)

; loading system definition from /home/rob/lispy/lispy-0.5/lispy.asd into

...

2010-01-06 23:13:25 "Initializing Lispy system on SBCL 1.0.29.11.debian" 
2010-01-06 23:13:25 "Fetching http://common-lisp.net/project/lispy/repository/map.lisp-expr" 
2010-01-06 23:13:27 "Fetching http://common-lisp.net/project/lispy/repository/map.lisp-expr.asc" 
gpg: Signature made Fri 25 Dec 2009 01:19:20 PM EST using DSA key ID 7CF49723
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING {AA5E5E9}>:
  GPG verification of map /var/cache/common-lisp-controller/1000/sbcl/local/home/rob/lispy/maps/map.lisp-expr with signature /var/cache/common-lisp-controller/1000/sbcl/local/home/rob/lispy/maps/map.lisp-expr.asc failed: "gpg: Signature made Fri 25 Dec 2009 01:19:20 PM EST using DSA key ID 7CF49723
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
"

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY ] Retry performing #<ASDF:LOAD-OP NIL {AAA7F01}> on
              #<ASDF:SYSTEM "lispy" {ABF01E9}>.
  1: [ACCEPT] Continue, treating #<ASDF:LOAD-OP NIL {AAA7F01}> on
              #<ASDF:SYSTEM "lispy" {ABF01E9}> as having been successful.
  2: [ABORT ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(LISPY::VERIFY-MAP
 #P"/var/cache/common-lisp-controller/1000/sbcl/local/home/rob/lispy/maps/map.lisp-expr.asc"
 #P"/var/cache/common-lisp-controller/1000/sbcl/local/home/rob/lispy/maps/map.lisp-expr"
 #<PURI:URI http://common-lisp.net/project/lispy/repository/map.lisp-expr>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install gpg
- wget http://common-lisp.net/project/lispy/key.asc
- gpg --import key.asc

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/)? It is amazing.

Comment: I just tried quicklisp out based on this response, and found that it was extremely easy to use with sbcl. It's definitely worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, I just discovered a number of lisp packages are in Ubuntu's apt repository, including Hunchentoot. Amazing! How did I not know about this?

Comment: Well, yes, but they are often outdated.  I have good experience with clbuild.

Comment: even worse than being out of date, the dependencies didn't seem to be in sync.